# Alguém me ajuda por favor meu carrossel não muda de foto

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TPM-Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="navbar-brand">
               <img src="" alt="Logo Tpm">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Home</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Sobre nós</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Historias contadas</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Envie sua Historia</button>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="teste1.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="teste2.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="teste3.jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

É preciso incluir o ficheiro JS do Bootstrap.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Existe um parâmetro para as imagens mudarem mais rapidamente.

```
<div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="2000">
```

Quando o cursor está por cima da imagem a imagem não muda.